# How to export the same code as both an R6RS and R7RS library

Tags: scheme, r6rs, r7rs

I have written some procedures that I want to package as both an R6RS library and an R7RS library. The procedures are in a file named `mylib.scm`:

```lisp
(define (multiplier n)  ; Private
  (lambda (x)
    (* n x)))

(define double (multiplier 2))  ; Public
(define triple (multiplier 3))  ; Public
```

To expose the procedures as an R7RS library, I created a file `mylib.sld`:

```lisp
(define-library (mylib)
  (export double
          triple)
  (import (scheme base))
  (include "mylib.scm"))
```

How do I similarly export the procedures as an R6RS library? To avoid code repetition, both R6RS and R7RS libraries should share the same code.

Comment: Which Scheme implementation are you using? `include` seems like the right idea. What have you tried that isn't working?

Comment: ["...If you write a library for one standard, it is not importable in implementations that have only the other standard ... They just use a different surface syntax for the library definition language"](https://groups.google.com/g/scheme-reports-wg2/c/YxVutAvKdaw/m/9JpMQ-A6BQAJ)

Comment: @PeterWinton I am not using any particular Scheme implementation. `include` is not in R6RS.